# I got a ReferenceError: “browser is not defined” in the console when I try create Bookmark in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying create a bookmarks (on this case in firefox)

API/bookmarks/create

my code is :

```html
<!doctype html>
<HTML lang="de">
 <HEAD>
  
  <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
  <link   href = 'https://office.spdns.de/System/TDL/Images/Browser/Company.ico' rel = 'SHORTCUT ICON'>

  <link rel="manifest" href="bookmark/manifest.json">

  <link   href = 'https://office.spdns.de/TDL/Common/CSS/Default.css'            rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>
  <link   href = 'https://office.spdns.de/TDL/Common/CSS/Formular_OnLine.css'    rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY lang=DE vLink=blue link=blue bgColor=white>
  <form action='https://office.spdns.de/TDL/Tools/WebExtensions.php' name='WebExtensions' id='WebExtensions' method='post' >
      <BR>

<script>

function onCreated(node) {
  console.log(node);
}

var createBookmark = browser.bookmarks.create({
  title: "Set time of work",
  url: "https://office.spdns.de/TDL/Tools/WebExtensions.php"
});

createBookmark.then(onCreated);

</script>
  </form>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "BookmarkOnce",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "Bookmark this page once in your employment",
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks"
  ]
}